# Ionic 3 - Multiple tables in indexedDB

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3, storage, indexeddb

I want to use two tables in the indexedDB but the inoic 3 documentation is not very good at this point.

in app.modules I imported the IonicStorageModule

```
IonicStorageModule.forRoot()
```

Then in my storage-uitls.ts file I tried to generate two tables in the constructor like it is mentioned [here](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-storage/issues/33#issuecomment-341770523)

```
constructor(private storage: Storage) {
  console.log("---------------")
  this.gpsData = new Storage({
    name: '__my_custom_db',
    storeName: '_contacts',
    driverOrder: ['indexeddb', 'sqlite', 'websql'],
  });
  this.serviceData = new Storage({
    name: '__my_custom_db',
    storeName: '_media',
    driverOrder: ['indexeddb', 'sqlite', 'websql'],
  });
}
```

But this doesn't work. I just get the default generated table in the indexedDB.

Anyone know how to generate my own tables and acces them?

Answer (score 2):

My setup for an IONIC 4 project (I've not tried it in a IONIC 3 project):

```
import { Storage } from '@ionic/storage';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-tab1',
  templateUrl: 'tab1.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['tab1.page.scss']
})
export class Tab1Page implements OnInit {

  private newReleasesDB: any;

  constructor() {
    this.newReleasesDB = new Storage({
      name: '__myCustom_db',
      storeName: '_newReleases',
      driverOrder: ['sqlite', 'indexeddb', 'websql', 'localstorage']
    });
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    // get saved records from Storage
    this.newReleasesDB.get('keyname').then((data: any) => {
        // do stuff with the data in storage
    });

  }
}
```

This works with multiple stores in the same DB, like so:

```
import { Storage } from '@ionic/storage';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-tab1',
  templateUrl: 'tab1.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['tab1.page.scss']
})
export class Tab1Page implements OnInit {

  private newReleasesDB: any;
  private myFrendsDB: any;

  constructor() {
    this.newReleasesDB = new Storage({
      name: '__myCustom_db',
      storeName: '_newReleases',
      driverOrder: ['sqlite', 'indexeddb', 'websql', 'localstorage']
    });

    this.myFrendsDB = new Storage({
      name: '__myCustom_db',
      storeName: '_myFriends',
      driverOrder: ['sqlite', 'indexeddb', 'websql', 'localstorage']
    });
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    // get saved records from Storage
    this.newReleasesDB.get('keyname').then((data: any) => {
        // do stuff with the data in storage
    });

    // get saved friends from Storage
    this.myFrendsDB.get('keyname').then((data: any) => {
        // do stuff with the data in storage
    });    
  }
}
```

If you're having trouble try clearing your storage and running the script again.